# how to add two urls for the same page for two different sites respectively in multi site code base

Tags: php, laravel

we are working on three sites in laravel that are using the same code base and are managed via git. 
what i want to do is have different url prefix for one site compared to the other two. 
Lets say we have speaker profiles and the url is like 
- {site one url}/speaker/{speaker slug}
-{site two url}/speaker/{speaker slug}
For the third site i want to have
-{site three url}/talent/{speaker slug}

I tried adding two route in web.php but that would enable both links at the same time and can cause duplicate content issue when getting the site ranked

Comment: set it up using the .env file. You can add any of your variables there, import them in config/app.php and so do something like config('app.prefix') in the code

Comment: I'm new to laravel , 
Can you give me more description. 
I have the routes like this at the moment. 

 Route::get('speaker', 'FrontController@innerListings')->name('speaker_list');

    Route::get('speaker/{slug}', 'FrontController@viewCelebrity')->name('speaker_view');

    Route::get('speaker/category', 'FrontController@innerListings')->name('category_list');

Comment: Please update your question with the routes, but it's all about the .env file. The routes don't need to be changed. You could also do route prefixing using the .env file